# Unable to print from Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing

Several Win 7 Pro PCs I use have become unable to print from the latest edition of Chrome.  More specifically they do not print anything on Drive.  They will print a few docs from Drive, but then stop printing anything from Drive.  You can try to print something, watch it go into the print queue, see the file in the spool directory, but nothing comes out.  Also if you try to print to an xps printer or save to pdf, you are given the option to name the file, but no file is created.  You can however still print from Google mail.

You can also print test pages from printer properties, print from local programs such as Word etc.  You can also use IE to access Google drive and print things this way.

Only printing from Drive using Chrome seems to be affected.

Any help appreciated